# Как вставить значения из массива в строку?

Tags: php, массивы, строки

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как вставить значения из массива в строку?

Вот пример того что нужно:

Здесь я получаю массив

```
$keys = explode(",", $keywords);
$key = $keys['0'];
```

из ключей указанных через запятую

> key1, key2, key3, key4, ...

Далее я получаю переменную описания (description):

```
$description = $modx->resource->get('description');
```

в формате

> Здесь начинается текст с ключом {$key} который должен отобразиться ещё
>   и здесь {$key} , а после должен идти рандомный текст.

Вообщем смысл в следующем, нужно получить ключи в виде `$key['0']` из массива и вставить их в переменную `$description`, а отображать из переменной `{$key}`.

Comment: `str_replace` или что?

Comment: Приведите пример данных массива, `description`, и то, что вы хотите получить.